# Wordpress Resize Image and show as thumb in post

Tags: images

I have set crop in functions.php to resize Images for Posts.

Codex from Wordpress: [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size), [post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

```
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 100, true); //size of thumbs
  add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 180, 180, true ); //(cropped)
```

Usage is like below

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumb' ); } ?>
```

But it will not resize the thumb and shows the original size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you upload the image before you added the new size? WP will not resize the images on-the-fly, you'll have to regenerate sizes that were added after upload.

Comment: It is taking on the fly with WPeMatico. Also tried with this [link](http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding new image sizes, you might need to rebuild your thumbnails. I have used [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) after encountering a similar issue, and it worked fine.